# Nested TikZ pics (double angle symbol)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, angle

**Edit:** @js bibra pointed me to [How do I mark an angle with multiple arcs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457827/how-do-i-mark-an-angle-with-multiple-arcs/457830#457830)

It seems like my question is kind of a duplicate, but there is still the matter of whether it makes sense and how to nest pics, -and how is the calling syntax from `angle` is achieved?

---

I want to define my own pic that create a double angle like this:

[image: Double angle]

Optimally the new double angle pic, `dangle` should work like the normal `angle`. My attempt is to create a new pic, where the angle is drawn twice:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 0.5 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {angles}
\tikzset{
    pics/dangle/.style args={#1--#2--#3}{
        code={
        \coordinate (AA) at #1;
        \coordinate (BB) at #2;
        \coordinate (CC) at #3;
 %       \draw pic [draw, angle radius=6 mm] {angle = AA--BB--CC};  %not ok
 %       \draw pic [draw, angle radius=7 mm] {angle = AA--BB--CC};  %not ok
       \draw[red] (AA)--(CC); %just for testing
        }
    }
}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,3);
    \draw pic [draw, green] {angle = A--B--C};   
    \draw pic {dangle={(A)--(B)--(C)}} ;
    \draw[thick] (A) node[right]{A} -- (B) node[left]{B} -- (C) node[right]{C};  
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image: Triangle with green angle]

I can not use `angle` within my own pic. Is it possible to nest pics? How? I created the temp coordinates `(AA)`, `(BB)` and `(CC)` because this is written in the manual:

> The three points ⟨A⟩, ⟨B⟩, and ⟨C⟩ must be the names of nodes or
> coordinates; you cannot use direct coordinates like “(1,1)” here.

-but I can still not make it work!

An other thing is that the calling syntax is not the same `angle = A--B--C` vs `dangle={(A)--(B)--(C)}`. Can someone explain why it is that way or how to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[tikz, border =3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {angles}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=right:A] (A) at (5,0);
\coordinate[label= left:B] (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at (2,3);
%
\pic [draw=green, double] {angle = A--B--C};
%   
\draw[thick]    (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\draw[red]      (C) -- (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you looking for? Distance between arcs lines you can adjust with `double distance=dimension`, for example `double distance=5pt`, which you add to `\pic` options.

**Addendum 1:**
now i recognize, that your question is actually duplicate to question for which you provide a link. If you like to nest more `pic`, just write it more with different `angle radius`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border =3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {angles}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=right:A] (A) at (5,0);
\coordinate[label= left:B] (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at (2,3);
% see different angle radius
\pic [draw=green, angle radius=7mm] {angle = A--B--C}; 
\pic [draw=green, angle radius=8mm] {angle = A--B--C};
\pic [draw=green, angle radius=9mm] {angle = A--B--C};
%   
\draw[thick]    (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\draw[red]      (C) -- (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum 2:**
It seems that your problem is to correct your style `\dangle` definition. It can't be defined on the way, as you try. Instead you can define new command, which will draw two arcs for angle mark:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 0.5 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {angles}
\newcommand\dangle[3]{ % <---
        \pic [draw, angle radius=6 mm] {angle = #1--#2--#3};
        \pic [draw, angle radius=7 mm] {angle = #1--#2--#3};
                     }

 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=right:A] (A) at (5,0);
\coordinate[label= left:B] (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at (2,3);
%
\dangle{A}{B}{C};
\draw[thick]    (A) -- (B) -- (C); 
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

by which you will get:

[image]

In the case, that you like to have colored arcs, than you only need add color to angle definition. For example

```
\pic [draw=green, angle radius=6 mm] {angle = #1--#2--#3}
\pic [draw=red,   angle radius=7 mm] {angle = #1--#2--#3}
```

which yield to:

[image]

On a similar way you can define command for even more arcs' marks for particular angle.

Comment: Yes nice, and I guess, that I can make a triple angle by techniques from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38431/triple-lines-in-tikz . Though I would like to know if it is possible in the way I started: nested pics!?

Comment: Please see answer from js bibra and edit.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, why? What you miss in my answer. As now see, your question is duplicate to question which link you provide ...

Comment: I do not miss anything - your answer is perfect. The reason I do not delete my question is the theoretical aspect about nesting pics and the calling syntax for angle.

Comment: Ok now my question is going to be closed anyway - guess I will never know

Comment: @hpekristiansen, in addendum to my answer I belive that you can find answers for your (sub)questions. More details yoou can find in *TikZ & PGF manual* , chapter 41 Angle Library, pp 568 -- 569.

Comment: Thanks, but I already read the manual - and I quote the manual in my question.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, sorry, your questions, considering your comments become unclear. What is exactly your problem? Please, edit your question and clarify there what is your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111728/discussion-between-hpekristiansen-and-zarko).

Answer (score 1):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457830/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[double arc/.style={double,double distance=2pt},
%                       triple arc/.style={double distance=4pt,
%                       pic actions/.append code=\tikzset{postaction={draw}}}
]
    \coordinate (A) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,3);
 \draw[thick] (A) node[right]{A} -- (B) node[left]{B} -- (C) node[right]{C};  
\draw   pic [draw,double arc,angle radius=1cm] {angle=A--B--C};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - I do not know why I did not find that. Seem like my question is a duplicate.