# Marking angles in tkz-euclide picture

Tags: tkz-euclide, tikz-angles

I'm looking for help using the tkzMarkAngle in the following code, I have tried to follow the help from here,[How do I mark an angle with multiple arcs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457827/how-do-i-mark-an-angle-with-multiple-arcs) but it does not render.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}


\begin{document}


        \begin{tikzpicture}     
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1){B} 
\tkzDefPoint(2.8,3){C} 
\tkzDefPoint(5,2.5){D} 
\tkzDefPoint(5,-2.5){E} 
\tkzDefPoint(4,-3){F} 
\tkzDefPoint(2,-1){G} 
\tkzDefPoint(3.1,1.5){P} 
\tkzDefPoint(3.8,-1.9){Q} 

\tkzDrawSegment[thick](B,D)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](G,E)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](F,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed, thick](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed, thick](G,A)

\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[above](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[right](D){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](E){$E$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[below](F){$F$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](G){$G$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[above](P){$P$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](Q){$Q$}

\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,P,Q)

%\tkzMarkAngle[arc=1,type=|,size=2 cm](A,P,F)
%\tkzMarkAngle[arc=11,size=2 cm](A,Q,C)

\end{tikzpicture}
        
        
\end{document}
```

I have hidden the two lines of code that make the code not work just so people can see the output before I try to mark the angles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure what exactly want to achieve, because there are several mistakes in your use of the options for `\tkzMarkAngle`:

- The option `type` does not exist for the `\tkzMarkAngle` macro, I assume that you mean the option `mark`.
- The `arc` option expects between one and three instances of the letter `l`, not of the number `1`.
- The `size` option seems to expect an integer (representing centimeters) and not a dimension.

Apart from that, I would suggest that you let Ti*k*Z calculate the position of `A`, `P` and `Q` since you use a package that is actually made for calculating such things:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}     
%\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1){B} 
\tkzDefPoint(2.8,3){C} 
\tkzDefPoint(5,2.5){D} 
\tkzDefPoint(5,-2.5){E} 
\tkzDefPoint(4,-3){F} 
\tkzDefPoint(2,-1){G} 
\tkzInterLL(B,D)(G,E)
\tkzGetPoint{A}
%\tkzDefPoint(3.1,1.5){P} 
%\tkzDefPoint(3.8,-1.9){Q} 
\tkzInterLL(B,D)(C,F)
\tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzInterLL(G,E)(C,F)
\tkzGetPoint{Q}

\tkzDrawSegment[thick](B,D)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](G,E)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](F,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed, thick](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed, thick](G,A)

\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[above](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[right](D){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](E){$E$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[below](F){$F$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](G){$G$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](P){$P$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below left](Q){$Q$}

\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,P,Q)

%\tkzMarkAngle[arc=1,type=|,size=2 cm](A,P,F)
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=l, size=1, mark=|, draw=red](B,P,Q)
%\tkzMarkAngle[arc=11,size=2 cm](A,Q,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll, size=1, draw=red](P,Q,G)

\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed and thanks for the explanations, I am still trying to learn this package.